# How to update hibernate cache if someone update database manually from backend?

Tags: database, hibernate

I want to update my hibernate cache if someone updated the database manually. I have lots of data coming through so I cannot afford to clear data all the time or rely on "timeToLiveSeconds" to update. I want something to update the cache memory as soon as there is any changes in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to code against the SPIs of Hibernate and possibly also against the API of your cache provider, you can implement this. You just need access to the cache regions and invalidate them per query space (table) or individual entries which are keyed by primary key.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to identify the same. How the cache come to know if someone modifies the value from the backend. You have to identify those sets of value and modify the cache at regular interval.

Comment: there must be some way. I searched online and found that debezium can help this problem out but i wanted to search some other ways as well. The amount to data traffic in my application is very heavy and for that reason I need some way to update the cache or some way to notify the cache if the database has been updated.